# GDAL: using the -R function in raster2psql creates errors

Tags: postgis, raster, gdal

I'm loading jp2 rasters into my PostgreSQL/PostGIS, and everything works fine unless I use -R in the commands:

```
raster2pgsql -s 28356 -I -C -M -R -l 8 10cmimagery.jp2 -F -t 250x250 imagery.10cmimageryl8r | psql -h localhost -U postgres -d GIS
```

The error is:

```
ERROR:  rt_band_load_offline_data: Cannot open offline raster: 10cmimagery.jp2
CONTEXT:  SQL function "st_transform" statement 1
```

If I omit the -R there are no errors and the jp2 file imports correctly. I'd like to read the raster from the original file rather than import it into the database ideally.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a permissions issue.

When you use the -R option, it's the postgres process that needs to be able to read the file where as pulling the file in the user loading the file only needs to have access.

Verify that the account you are running postgres under has rights to your folder path and that the path you specified in load is one that  the postgres account can access.

Comment: Would you know to check what the Postgres rights are? Is it a windows environment variable thing, or something inside the database? Cheers

Comment: windows environment thing.  If you right click folder, make sure the account that postgres service is running under has rights read rights to the folder.  If you need it to access a network location, then you need to have the postgres service run under a user network domain account

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this, but it was a combination of solutions that all need to be undertaken for the fix to work. Firstly, the full path of the raster needs to be entered when using the -R switch. I created and used a new superuser account in PostgresQL with extra permissions, instead of using the default postgres user. I then loaded the query files into the database and ran them, mentioned in this site:

https://duncanjg.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/the-basics-of-postgis-raster/

There might have been a few other things I tweaked around with that I can't remember, but the above steps were the main ones. I know that the correct GDAL driver needs to be installed.

Comment: One note - someone noted a bug with using -R in raster2pgsql that it tries to transform instead of set.  So your out-db ends up being an in-db.  You should get rid of -s (or combine it with -Y) -  See this ticket - https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/3738  you also need out db GUC enabled, but you probably did that already